# UTF-8 characters displaying incorrectly in PHP (when outputting result from MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I inserted some data from phpMyAdmin, it seems to be fine on phpMyAdmin [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeSFU.png), but when I use PHP output the result from MYSQL, it becomes: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpJQA.png)

PHP code:

```
function showTableRows($db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forums ORDER BY id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $forum_id = $row['forum_id'];
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo '<a href="viewforum.php?forum='. $forum_id .'">'. $row['name'] .'</a>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<small>'. $row['description'] .'</small>';
                ......
```

MYSQL collation already set to **utf8_general_ci**
HTML charset already set to **utf-8**

What am I missing??

Comment: Have you tried using `htmlentities` to encode your data before outputting it?

Comment: I just tried htmlentities($row['name']), but still the same.

Comment: htmlentities is not the cure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because you are missing the charset option when connecting:

example:
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf-8', etc...

I don't see the connection line in your code, so, I can't know for sure.

Comment: After adding charset=utf8 when connecting, it displays ok now. Thanks.